# Conditional url rewrite and proxy

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, seo

I have a Javascript app, and for Social Sharing puposes I would like to return the result form another server when the facebook crawler visits the page.

Basically, if I detect a Social bot, I would like to do:

GET https://example.net/shared/route/123 -> GET https://rendered.example.net/robots/shared/route/123

I am failing to complete this, as I cannot use `proxy_pass` or `try_files` inside an `if` statement.

What I've tried:

```
    location /shared/route/ {
            if ($http_user_agent ~ (?!(facebookexternalhit|Facebot|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet))) {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
            }
            rewrite /shared/(.*) /robots/$1 break;
            proxy_pass https://rendered.example.net/;
    }
```

But I receive the error:

```
"try_files" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/webapp:22
```

And I've also tried

```
location /shared/route/ {
        if ($http_user_agent ~ (?!(facebookexternalhit|Facebot|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet))) {
                rewrite /shared(.*) /robots/$1 break;
                proxy_pass https://rendered.example.net/;
        }
}
```

But then I receive:

```
"proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/app:24
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Both servers are defined in same server block or different? Better post complete config with all relevant sections

Comment: Try: `proxy_pass https://rendered.example.net;`

Comment: @RichardSmith That helped! It is now working. Feel free to add it as an answer and I will accept it. Thank you.